# Elevator Control Using UPPAAL or NuSMV

Tags: validation, system, nusmv, uppaal

I am new to NuSMV and UPPAAL and am working on this problem.
Can any one provide a solution to the following question?

Model   and analyze a   control system  of  an  elevator-system of  your
own design  serving a   number  of  floors  (say    4   or  5)  and with    a
number  of  liXs    (say    2   or  3)  and with    a   number  of  users   being   on
individual  floors  and with    individual  wishes  for gelng   to  different
floors. The system  may:
•  allow    the user    may     indicate    that    a   liX is  required    at  a   certain floor,
and/or  needs   to  go  up  or  down    and/or  is  requested   to  go  to  a
certain floor
•  or   the user    may --  once    inside  the liX --  request actual  floor.
•  In   order   to  move    the doors   must    be  closed. 
•  floors   cannot  be  skiped. 
•  The  ini6al  posi6on of  all the liXs    is  floor   1.  a   The elevator    is
controlled  by  only    one buPon   by  which   it  is  possible    to  order   the 
elevator    to  the floor   where   you stand.

Comment: Hi, stack-overflow is not a free-coding service. Please edit your question with your attempt at solving this exercise, and a concise description of the difficulties/problems you encountered along the way, as well as a precise question you want to ask, which should not be *"fix and complete this for me"*. For more information, please consult [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the program for you but I can give you some hints.

Decide which entities to include and what states the entities should be able to have. For example: Button, cabin, controller, door...can be entities and the entities can have states. The button can be pressed, the cabin can be moving or idle, the door can be open or closed etc.

Model the entities as modules with SMV. If you don't know SMV then try learn it from simple examples.

Decide which specification that should be satisfied. For example: The elevator should never change floors while the doors are open etc.

If you practice with other example SMV programs then you will find it easier to get started. If you post code where you make an effort to solve the problem we can help you more and better.

Comment: Thanks alot Dj Dac.
Really appreciate your effort.
I have done most of the coding.
Will share it when it is completed.